Querydsl fetch very slow when there is oneTomany relationship in entity
On a project we use Querydsl to create dynamic queries and apply sorting ang pagination. The following code is very slow when having the oneTomany and manytoone relationships in the following objects ticket, payment and ticket_payment.
Especially when applying pagination at this part it takes 10+ minutes to returns only 10 items.
List<?> result = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, query).fetch();

The pageable values are offset=0, size=10 and there are values for sorting.
In the produced query there is no part "fetch first ? rows only" added so I guess it takes too long beacuse it loads ticket and ticket_payment tables? Ticket table has 100K rows and Ticket_payment 120k. When running the same query in sql developer it takes <4 sec to return 50 rows.
What improvemnts could be made, in order to get results faster? Can fetch() method be customized to run faster?
QueryDSL fetch code:
org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

Querydsl querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, (new PathBuilderFactory()).create(<EntityClass>.class));
JPQLQuery<?> query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);

//TODO: prepare your query here 

//Get the count
Long totalElements = query.fetchCount();

//Apply the pagination
List<?> result = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, query).fetch();
//Returns 10 items but takes more than 10min

//return a paged response
return new PageImpl<>(result, pageable, totalElements);

And the following entities and tables
ticket
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TICKET")
    public class Ticket implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "TICKET_ID", nullable = false)
        private Long id;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Ticket")
        private Set<TicketPayment> ticketPayments= new HashSet<>();
    ...
    }

payment
@Entity
@Table(name = "PAYMENT")
public class Payment implements Serializable {

@Id()
@Column(name = "PAYMENT_ID")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "PAYMENT_CODE")
private String code;

join table
@Entity
@Table(name = "TICKET_PAYMENT")
@IdClass(TicketPaymentPK.class)
public class TikcetPayment{


@Id
@Column(name = "TICKET_ID", nullable = false, precision = 0)
private long ticketId;

@Id
@Column(name = "PAYMENT_ID", nullable = false, precision = 0)
private long paymentId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TICKET_ID", referencedColumnName = "TICKET_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Ticket ticket;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PAYMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PAYMENT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Payment payment;
...

Composite key
public class TicketPaymentPKimplements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = "TICKET_ID", nullable = false, precision = 0)
private long ticketId;
@Id
@Column(name = "PAYMENT_ID", nullable = false, precision = 0)
private long paymentId;


This is a known problem in Query DSL that it calls a count when it shouldn't. How I fixed it was by creating a custom repository and implementing the findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) without the count:
public interface MyCustomRepository<T, I> extends Repository<T, I> {

    Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);

}

public class MyCustomRepositoryImpl<T, I extends Serializable> extends QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor<T> implements MyCustomRepository<T, I> {

    private final EntityPath<T> path;
    private final Querydsl querydsl;
    private final EntityManager em;
    private final Class<T> entityType;

    public MyCustomRepositoryImpl(final JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, final EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager, SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE, null);
        this.em = entityManager;
        this.entityType = entityInformation.getJavaType();
        // get the fields from the base class rather than instantiate them
        this.path = Fields.getIgnoreAccess(this, Fields.getDeclaredField(QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor.class, "path"));
        this.querydsl = Fields.getIgnoreAccess(this, Fields.getDeclaredField(QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor.class, "querydsl"));
    }

    public Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        JPQLQuery<T> jpqlQuery = (JPQLQuery<T>) createQuery(predicate);
        jpqlQuery = querydsl.applySorting(pageable.getSort(), jpqlQuery)
                .offset(pageable.getOffset())
                .limit(pageable.getPageSize() + 1L);

        // we fetch one extra entity to correcly calculate the page
        List<P> result = jpqlQuery.fetch();

        int size = result.size();
        if (size > pageable.getPageSize()) {
            result.remove(size - 1);
        }
        return new PageImpl<>(result, pageable, pageable.getOffset() + size);     
    }
}

To use this custom repository you also need:
public class CustomRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends Repository<S, I>, S, I>
        extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, I> {

    public CustomRepositoryFactoryBean(final Class<? extends T> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(final EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new CustomRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }
}

and
public class CustomRepositoryFactory extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public CustomRepositoryFactory(final EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFragments getRepositoryFragments(final RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
        RepositoryFragments fragments = super.getRepositoryFragments(metadata);

        if (MyCustomeRepository.class.isAssignableFrom(metadata.getRepositoryInterface())) {
            JpaEntityInformation<?, Serializable> entityInformation = getEntityInformation(metadata.getDomainType());

            Object queryableFragment = instantiateClass(MyCustomRepositoryImpl.class, entityInformation, entityManager);

            RepositoryFragments newFragments = RepositoryFragments.of(RepositoryFragment.implemented(queryableFragment));
            fragments = newFragments.append(fragments);
        }

        return fragments;
    }
}

And then in the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation you have to specify:
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CustomRepositoryFactoryBean.class,
        ...)

and make sure all your repositories that want to use this functionality need to implement the MyCustomRepository interface instead of QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor.
Note: the Fields.getIgnoreAccess and Fields.getDeclaredField are just some utility methods that return those 2 fields from the base class via reflection since they are private and there is no need to reinitialize them to occupy more memory, feel free to implement them as you like.
